# TextMate on OS X - tab completion not working

Tags: textmate, ruby-on-rails, tab-completion

What gives. I'm obviously being really thick.

I open a file using TextMate (mate r1577 (2010-11-18)) on Mac OS X (10.5.8)

When I try and use tab to complete a snippet, for example `vp<TAB>` does not expand to the `validates_presence_of` rails snippet I expected ?

Is there something I need to do to turn it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure TextMate has recognized the language used in file as *Ruby on Rails* and not just *Ruby*. Along the bottom of the editor window, towards the left side, TextMate tells you what language it thinks the file is you're editing. For example, here it has detected *Python*:

[image]

If you click on that language name you'll get a list of languages to choose from. Choose *Ruby on Rails* and TextMate will load the snippets for developing a Rails application.